# For some reason "sudo ssh -w any -o Tunnel=ethernet root@remote" creates tun devices instead of tap devices

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunneling, tap

To connect multiple tunnel endpoints to a common bridge interface, I have to create a Layer 2 tunnel over ssh. The server is Ubuntu 10.04, the client is Ubuntu 14.04. I have enabled

```
PermitTunnel yes
PermitRootLogin yes
```

in the servers /etc/sshd_config. When I'm connecting with `sudo ssh -w any:any -o "Tunnel=ethernet" root@remote` I get a tun device instead of the expected tap device. If I change "`PermitTunnel yes`" to "`PermitTunnel ethernet`" on the server, I get a "channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed" error message and no tunnel device at all.

I'm at a loss, because I'm positive that this used to work at some point in the past (with different machines and probably Linux versions).

Comment: what openssh version do you have on the ubuntu 10? I would guess it will be pretty old (EOL?) and it might miss some features.

Comment: The sshd version on Ubuntu 10 should not be the problem. The man page documents the `PermitTunnel` option with both `point-to-point` and `ethernet` as valid values. Anyway, the version is 1:5.3p1.

Comment: That's a bit old Ubuntu you are running. Did you try connecting with a more recent version? With a live-cd maybe?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but as I wrote in my question: the server is Ubuntu 10.04 (pretty old, I admit) and the client is Ubuntu 14.04LTS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have the same problem. According to my tests, it is not related to the server, instead it has something to do with the client. Either ssh build and configuration, either due to the local network configuration.

I've been able to create a tap interface between my laptop and all of my devices but when I tried to tunnel between the devices, only tun interfaces were created.

[edit]
The workaround consists in putting the "-o" before the "-w" like this :

```
ssh -o Tunnel=ethernet -w any:any root@remote
```

instead of :

```
ssh -w any:any -o Tunnel=ethernet root@remote
```

I tried it myself, it works, here is the source : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/1316017